# Creating a word length frequency table in python

Tags: python, file

I have the following code:

```
import re

def get_filename():
    """gets the file"""
    filename = input("Please enter filename: ")
    return filename
    
def get_words_from_file(filename):
    """getting the data and printing it word by word"""
    infile = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    outfile = infile.read().splitlines()
    words = []
    reading = False
    for let in outfile:
        if let.startswith("*** START OF")and reading == False:
            reading = True
        elif let.startswith("*** END OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE ***") or let.startswith("*** END"):
            return words
        elif reading:
            let = let.lower()
            words.extend(re.findall("[a-z]+[-'][a-z]+|[a-z]+[']?|[a-z]+", let))
    return words

def calculate(words):
    """gjhwjghwg2"""
    all_times = []
    max_word_length = 0
    number_of_words = len(words)
    average = sum(len(word) for word in words) / number_of_words
    for word in words:
        if len(word)>max_word_length:
            max_word_length=len(word)
    frequency = {word: 0 for word in words}
    for word in words:
        frequency[word] += 1
    max_frequency = max(frequency.values())
    
    result = (number_of_words, average, max_word_length, max_frequency)
    return result

def get_frequency(words):
    """ghjhgwejhgwjgw"""
    len_count = []
    frequency_1 = {word: 0 for word in words}
    for word in words:
        frequency_1[word] += 1
    answer = (frequency_1, len_count)
    return answer

def print_results(stats_tuple, lengthy):
    """calculate the goods"""
    (frequency_1, len_count) = lengthy
    (number_of_words, average, max_word_length, max_frequency) = stats_tuple
    print("")
    print("Word summary (all words):")
    print(" Number of words = {0}".format(number_of_words))
    print(" Average word length = {:.2f}".format(average))
    print(" Maximum word length = {0}".format(max_word_length))
    print(" Maximum frequency = {0}".format(max_frequency))
    print("")
    print(" Len  Freq")
    for word_len in range(1, max(len_count) + 1):
        print(f'{frequency_1}\t{len_count.get(frequency_1, 0)}')
    

def main():
    """ghkghwgjkwhgw"""
    filename = get_filename()
    data = get_words_from_file(filename)
    stats = calculate(data)
    lengthy = get_frequency(data)
    print_results(stats, lengthy)
main()
```

Without importing anything else, how would I make a table which prints the length and then the frequency.

For example:
In a file with the text of "a blah ba ba" it would print:

```
Len  Freq
   1     1
   2     2
   3     0
   4     1
```

What confuses me about this is how to add all the length of the words together, should I be making a new list with all the same length of words and then counting the length of that list, or is there a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
len_count = {}
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            word_len = len(word)
            if not word_len in len_count:
                len_count[word_len] = 1
            else:
                len_count[word_len] += 1
```

Then you can print the two columns:

```
print("Len\tFreq")
for word_len in range(1, max(len_count) + 1):
    print(f'{word_len}\t{len_count.get(word_len, 0)}')
```

EDIT: To handle empty files:

```
max_len_count = 0 if not len_count else max(len_count)
for word_len in range(1, max_len_count + 1):
    print(f'{word_len}\t{len_count.get(word_len, 0)}')
```

Comment: This counter code seems fine, but there is a small issue regarding the printing. From the question, it seems that the OP also wants to print the zero counts (see the len=3 freq=0 line in the example output).

Comment: `range(1, max(len_count))` will iterate up to `max(len_count) - 1`.

Comment: I have now edited this code and I am so close to figuring it out. When I run it I get the error, "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence" I know this is because len_count is empty. How would I go about getting the len_count from this?

Comment: for len_count to be empty, you must be reading from an empty file. I edited the answer to cover this case.

Comment: If you look at my code for the function, get_frequency(words), I am not making len_count be anything other than an empty []. This is the problem I don't know what to add to len_count.

Comment: Wait never mind I was typing [] instead of {}. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Counter` from the `collections` modules. Then loop over the lengths from 1 to the maximum count. If the length is not present in the counts dictionary then write `0`, otherwise write the corresponding value.

```
from collections import Counter

filename = 'test.txt'
with open(filename) as fin:
    words = fin.read().split()

counts = Counter(len(word) for word in words)

print('Len  Freq')

for length in range(1, max(counts.keys()) + 1):
    print(f'{length:4d} {counts.get(length, 0):5d}')
```

If the input file consists of:

```
a blah ba ba
```

then this gives:

```
Len  Freq
   1     1
   2     2
   3     0
   4     1
```

Note that the `max(counts.keys())` is written that way for clarity, but `max(counts)` could be used instead (because if you iterate over a dictionary, as `max` will do here - and a `Counter` object is essentially a dictionary - then you iterate over its keys).

This example assumes that you have a relatively small file that can be stored in memory. If you have a larger file then you could do something like the following, to avoid doing so:

```
from collections import Counter

filename = 'test.txt'

def iter_lengths(filename):
    with open(filename) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            for word in line.split():
                yield len(word)

counts = Counter(iter_lengths(filename))

print('Len  Freq')

for length in range(1, max(counts) + 1):
    print(f'{length:4d} {counts.get(length, 0):5d}')
```

Comment: Let's avoid bad-practices in answers? Please change `words = open(filename).read().split()` to `with open(filename) as fin: words = fin.read().split()`